# I need to receive the GPS coordinates on Delphi 11.3 - Android 11 every 5 minutes, even when the app is in background

Tags: android, delphi

I'm using Delphi 11.3 and I need to have an app which runs on Android (it would be great to have a similar code for iOS) that retrieve the GPS coordinates every 5 minutes even when the APP is in background.

I've been trying to do this but I cannot make it work. I tried timers, foreground services various components but it never works as expected.

This is the code I'm trying right now. It works just for a couple of seconds and receive just one location, then the APP terminates without any message.

I am keen to fix this on Android first, but I would like to have the same result on iOS also.

### Edit

I tried commenting this code:

```
FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER,
          Round(10 * 1000), 30, locationListener,
          TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);
```

and the app does not terminates any more. So something is wrong in there I guess.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.DialogService, FMX.Memo.Types, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo,

  // Manual
  System.Sensors,
  System.Permissions,
  Posix.Unistd,

  // Android
  Androidapi.JNI.Os,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.Telephony,
  Androidapi.JNI.App,
  FMX.Platform.Android,
  FMX.Helpers.Android,
  Androidapi.JNI.Net,
  Androidapi.JNI.Provider,
  Androidapi.JNI.Support,
  Androidapi.JNI.Location;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure LocationisChanged(location: JLocation);
    procedure StartAndroidGPS;
  public
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TLocationListener = class(TJavaLocal, JLocationListener)
  private
    [weak] FParent : TForm1;
  public
    constructor Create(AParent : TForm1);
    procedure onLocationChanged(location: JLocation); cdecl;
    procedure onProviderDisabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onProviderEnabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer; extras: JBundle); cdecl;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  locationListener: TLocationListener;
  FLocationManager: JLocationManager;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

constructor TLocationListener.Create(AParent: TForm1);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FParent := AParent;
end;

procedure TLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
begin
  FParent.LocationisChanged(location);
end;

procedure TLocationListener.onProviderDisabled(provider: JString);
begin
  //
end;
procedure TLocationListener.onProviderEnabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
begin
  //
end;
procedure TLocationListener.onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer; extras: JBundle);
begin
  //
end;

procedure TForm1.LocationisChanged(location: JLocation);
var
  lc: TLocationCoord2D;
begin
  // do whatever you need to do with the location here, for example:
  lc := TLocationCoord2D.Create(location.getLatitude, location.getLongitude);

  Memo1.Lines.Add(lc.Latitude.ToString + ' - ' + lc.Longitude.ToString);
end;

procedure TForm1.StartAndroidGPS;
var LocationManagerService: JObject;
    location: JLocation;
begin
  if not Assigned(FLocationManager) then
  begin
    LocationManagerService :=
      TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap(
      (LocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID
      );
    if not Assigned(locationListener) then
      locationListener := TLocationListener.Create(self);
  end;

   FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER,
          Round(10 * 1000), 30, locationListener,
            TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);

  // just to get started, ask the GPS for the Last Known Position (if any)
  location := FLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
  LocationisChanged(location);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Richiedo i permessi

  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([
    JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_PHONE_STATE),
    JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
    JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
    JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
    JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
    JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.CAMERA)
  ],
  procedure(const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray)
  begin
    if (Length(AGrantResults) = 6) and
       (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and
       (AGrantResults[1] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and
       (AGrantResults[2] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and
       (AGrantResults[3] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and
       (AGrantResults[4] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and
       (AGrantResults[5] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
      begin
        StartAndroidGPS;
      end
    else
    begin
      TDialogService.ShowMessage('you need to approve all the user rights!');
    end;
  end);

end;

end.
```

Comment: There's a demo here that might help you:
https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Demos/CrossPlatformLocation

Comment: thank you for the answer Dave. I was hoping to fix my code because their is a little too complex. I already tried their demo but I was not able to compile it. I guess I will have to try again.

Comment: To achieve what you want on Android, you must use a service, or if implementing it in Java, possibly with a descendant of the Worker class (Delphi is yet to support this). PS: I wrote the code for the demo that I linked to

Comment: Gread job you did there! Unfortunately I'm not able to compile it, I have opened a ticket. https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Playground/issues/18

Comment: There is a delphi demo app which does that and is installed in the following folder (if you have installed the demos...): "\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Device Sensors and Services\ForegroundLocationDemo"

Comment: What's the difference between the one in the delphi demos and the one Dave wrote?